# Sudden compile error in Android Studio; error: cannot find symbol class ComputableLiveData

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

I opened up my project and compiled and ran it, and I'm getting the error mentioned in the title, `error: cannot find symbol class ComputableLiveData`. I've built a local database using a Room abstraction over SQLite, and the error is occurring in `BundleDao_Impl.java`.

```
package com.weaberlumber.programmer.s4s_scan;

import android.arch.lifecycle.ComputableLiveData; //The error is here
import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData;
import android.arch.persistence.db.SupportSQLiteStatement;
import android.arch.persistence.room.EntityDeletionOrUpdateAdapter;
import android.arch.persistence.room.EntityInsertionAdapter;
import android.arch.persistence.room.InvalidationTracker.Observer;
import android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase;
import android.arch.persistence.room.RoomSQLiteQuery;
import android.arch.persistence.room.util.StringUtil;
```

I've tried deleting the build folder so that the file could be regenerated, but no luck.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This was fixed by adding the following implementation to the dependencies under `build.gradle` (Module: app)

```
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1'
```

Comment: Just to expand on your answer, here is overview of all architecture components libraries: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components if someone wonder what else is available